# Creating registry keys not working, no errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, registry, winreg

I'm trying to emulate the following registry script in python.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with notepad]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with notepad\command]
@="notepad %1"
```

My attempt looks like this.

```
import winreg as wreg
reg = wreg.ConnectRegistry(None, wreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)
root = wreg.OpenKey(reg, r'\*\shell', 0, wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

key = wreg.CreateKey(root, r'Open with notepad')
wreg.SetValue(key, None, wreg.REG_SZ, '')
wreg.FlushKey(key)

key2 = wreg.CreateKey(root, r'Open with notepad\command')
wreg.SetValue(key2, None, wreg.REG_SZ, 'notepad %1')
wreg.FlushKey(key2)

root.Close()
key.Close()
key2.Close()
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything. No errors are shown, but also no keys are added to the registry according to regedit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be [Registry Vitualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx), if the Python executable doesn't declare itself Vista-compatible.

Comment: That appears to be it. The keys appear under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`.